# google cloud hosting for database

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage

I want to host database on google cloud. My application is dating app  and I want to know monthly charges of initially accommodate 100,000 users with that the capacity to have 15 second video (5 mb max) for each user.

And also suggest hosting service for the apis.

Comment: Voting to close because service recommendations or pricing calculations are not programming and as such off topic at SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this following calculator to figure out the costs for your app,

https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/

google recommend Google Cloud Storage for Multimedia files, therefore look at the pricing options for that as well.

https://cloud.google.com/storage-options/